# node-red mqtt installation error

Tags: node.js, nvm

I'm trying to install node-red on ubuntu 14.04 lts.
I've installed nodejs and nvm, then i've launched:

```
git clone https://github.com/node-red/node-red.git
cd node-red
sudo npm install --production
```

I got this error:

```
....
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/uglify-js/2.4.13

npm ERR! Error: failed to fetch from registry: express
npm ERR!     at /usr/share/npm/lib/utils/npm-registry-client/get.js:139:12
npm ERR!     at cb (/usr/share/npm/lib/utils/npm-registry-client/request.js:31:9)
npm ERR!     at Request._callback (/usr/share/npm/lib/utils/npm-registry-client/request.js:136:18)
npm ERR!     at Request.callback (/usr/lib/nodejs/request/main.js:119:22)
npm ERR!     at Request.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/nodejs/request/main.js:212:58)
npm ERR!     at Request.emit (events.js:88:20)
npm ERR!     at ClientRequest.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/nodejs/request/main.js:412:12)
npm ERR!     at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:67:17)
npm ERR!     at HTTPParser.onIncoming (http.js:1261:11)
npm ERR!     at HTTPParser.onHeadersComplete (http.js:102:31)
npm ERR! You may report this log at:
npm ERR!     <http://bugs.debian.org/npm>
```

I've tried to use:

```
npm config set registry http://registry.npmjs.org/
sudo npm install --production
```

And now i got:

```
....
npm http 304 http://registry.npmjs.org/mqtt

npm ERR! Error: No compatible version found: mqtt@'>=0.3.0- <0.4.0-'
npm ERR! Valid install targets:
npm ERR! ["0.1.8","0.2.0","0.2.1","0.2.2","0.2.3","0.2.4","0.2.5"]
npm ERR!     at installTargetsError (/usr/share/npm/lib/cache.js:488:10)
npm ERR!     at next_ (/usr/share/npm/lib/cache.js:438:17)
npm ERR!     at next (/usr/share/npm/lib/cache.js:415:44)
npm ERR!     at /usr/share/npm/lib/cache.js:408:5
npm ERR!     at saved (/usr/share/npm/lib/utils/npm-registry-client/get.js:147:7)
npm ERR!     at Object.oncomplete (/usr/lib/nodejs/graceful-fs.js:230:7)
npm ERR! You may report this log at:
npm ERR!     <http://bugs.debian.org/npm>
```

How can i solve?